# Pthreads pool prematurely finishing, how can I make it work right?

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads, pool

I'm recently recompiled my server so that I can use multithreading in PHP (using pThreads).  I have already gotten pthreads working and used them in other scripts, however, getting them to work in a Pool is turning into a larger challenge than I thought.

Currently, I have this proof of concept script:

```php
$tArray = array();
class APIWork extends Collectable {
    protected $complete;
    public $status;
    public $file;
    public $url;
    public function __construct($pFile, $pUrl){
        //transfer all the variables to local variables
        $this->complete = false;
        $this->status = 'never ran';
        $this->file = $pFile;
        $this->url = $pUrl;
    }
    public function run(){
        $this->status = 'started';
        usleep(3000);
        $this->status = 'completed';
        $this->complete = true;
    }
    public function isGarbage() {
        return $this->complete;
    }
}
$pool = new Pool(3);
$counter = 0;
$filename = 'testfile';
$url = 'asdf';
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
    $tArray[$counter] = new Threaded();
    $pool->submit(new APIWork($filename, $url));
    $counter++;
}
$retArr = array();
$pool->collect(function(APIWork $task){
    global $retArr;
    //$task->join();
    $tmpObj = new stdclass();
    $tmpObj->filePath = $task->file;
    $tmpObj->url = $task->url;
    $tmpObj->status = $task->status;
    $tmpObj->complete = $task->complete;
    array_push($retArr, $tmpObj);
    return $task->isGarbage();
});
$pool->shutdown();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($retArr); //return the array of results
echo '</pre>';
```

What I wind up with is something that looks like this:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [filePath] => testfile
            [url] => asdf
            [status] => completed
            [complete] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [filePath] => testfile
            [url] => asdf
            [status] => started
            [complete] => 
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [filePath] => testfile
            [url] => asdf
            [status] => started
            [complete] => 
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [filePath] => testfile
            [url] => asdf
            [status] => started
            [complete] => 
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [filePath] => testfile
            [url] => asdf
            [status] => never ran
            [complete] => 
        )

)
```

It appears that even though I made sure to run the `$pool->shutdown();` command, the pthreads are not being allowed to finish.  Can somebody please help me to understand how to make the pthreads Pool allow the threads to finish.

Note: I'm using PHP 5.6.18 with Pthreads 2.0.10 on a Ubuntu webserver if that helps.

Also, I tried to model my code after the following, since I believe this guy is the ultimate authority on pThreads, but I added and removed to pass data in where I needed:
[pThreads Pool example by krakjoe](https://gist.github.com/krakjoe/9384409)

Comment: If the threads had not been joined, you would not get the result: Since you have a result, the ```Pool``` *has* been shutdown. Your ```isComplete``` should be named ```isGarbage``` and call to ```setGarbage``` removed, but none of that would cause the symptoms you describe, just waste memory. Is this code being executed inside a web server by any chance ?

Comment: I renamed `isComplete` to `isGarbage`, removed `setGarbage`, but still the same result.  Also, I believe the reason I'm getting the results is because they are initialized in the constructor for the `APIWork` class, and some of them are getting started because I `submit` the workes to the pool.  However, nothing is making them wait.  Previously I thought the `$pool->shutdown();` command would allow the threads to finish, either that or the `collect`, but I'm starting to question it.  Do I somehow need to call a join on each thread? (thank you for your reply sir!)

Comment: @JoeWatkins Also yes, it is on a web server, I moved it to a public area of our webserver so you can run it yourself and see the behavior. The various results will oscillate between completed, started, and never ran. Here is the link: http://public.rscivil.com/public/test/pThreadPoolTest.php